# How to get Excel file name when reading the file as inputstream

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, inputstream

Trying to read excel(*.xlsx) as binary input stream.
Currently using `OPCPackage`(Apache POI) to open the input stream and then reading the sheet using `XSSFReader`.

But could not find how can we fetch file name itself when reading as input stream.
Any help/suggestion is appreciated

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

Since you are getting input from input stream you can't get the file name.But if you are using file object then you can get the name.

Example:

```
File file = new File("/path/to/your/file.xlsx");
String fileName = file.getName().split(".")[0]; // "." is the file ext.
```